# Is there a downloadable app that will detect and install a wireless ethernet configuration?

Tags: wireless

I've tried various things to get my wireless ethernet to work, all to no avail.  It seems to me that if wired internet can work, then the wireless should also work.  Would be nice if Ubuntu had this feature.

Comment: Please mention the Ubuntu version you're using (12.04, 13.10, ...), if you're running a desktop or server and add the output of `lspci -nn` to your question - to run this command open a terminal using Ctrl+Alt+t.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has available many tools to help you set up your network connections.

For wireless connections you can try **wicd**, just tipe on a console:

`sudo apt-get install wicd`

[Official manual on wicd](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD)

That is pretty simple easy to use tool and will get your wireless network going.

Other great tool is **Network Manager**

`sudo apt-get install network-manager`

[Official manual on network manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager)

Don't forget that your wireless card needs to be recognized and the drivers installed just like in Windows.

You can see this if you do a:

`sudo ifconfig`

And see if there's a wireless card there.

Note: Ethernet card and wireless cards are to different things, you can have ethernet working and wireless not for example.

To have everything working your hardware needs to have the drivers installed, which the Ubuntu kernel does for most of the known hardware.

Comment: wicd required Network Manager to be uninstalled (I followed the man link). Moreover Network Manager is more a service than an application, only command line tools are part of that package. And NM is installed by default on Ubuntu Desktop installs.

Comment: Network Manager needs to be removed, i didn't knew that.